# Problems with installing 'aspell'

Tags: aspell

I am new to this community so I hope this is the right place to ask this question. I am trying to install [aspell stable version](http://aspell.net/), a spell checker software which I intend to use for my latex documents, on Windows 7 using gcc compiler. In aspell directory, I typed `./configure`. Here's the result:

```
checking build system type... x86_64-pc-mingw64
checking host system type... x86_64-pc-mingw64
checking target system type... x86_64-pc-mingw64
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /usr/bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... no
checking for g++... g++
checking whether the C++ compiler works... yes
checking for C++ compiler default output file name... a.exe
checking for suffix of executables... .exe
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
checking whether g++ accepts -g... yes
checking for style of include used by make... GNU
checking dependency style of g++... gcc3
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking whether gcc understands -c and -o together... yes
checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3
configure: WARNING: Libtool does not cope well with whitespace in `pwd`
checking how to print strings... printf
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /usr/bin/sed
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /usr/bin/grep
checking for egrep... /usr/bin/grep -E
checking for fgrep... /usr/bin/grep -F
checking for ld used by gcc... c:/mingw/x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe
checking if the linker (c:/mingw/x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe) is GNU ld... yes
checking for BSD- or MS-compatible name lister (nm)... /c/MinGW/bin/nm
checking the name lister (/c/MinGW/bin/nm) interface... BSD nm
checking whether ln -s works... no, using cp -pR
checking the maximum length of command line arguments... 8192
checking whether the shell understands some XSI constructs... yes
checking whether the shell understands "+="... yes
checking how to convert x86_64-pc-mingw64 file names to x86_64-pc-mingw64 format... func_convert_file_msys_to_w32
checking how to convert x86_64-pc-mingw64 file names to toolchain format... func_convert_file_msys_to_w32
checking for c:/mingw/x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe option to reload object files... -r
checking for objdump... objdump
checking how to recognize dependent libraries... file_magic ^x86 archive import|^x86 DLL
checking for dlltool... dlltool
checking how to associate runtime and link libraries... func_cygming_dll_for_implib
checking for ar... ar
checking for archiver @FILE support... @
checking for strip... strip
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking command to parse /c/MinGW/bin/nm output from gcc object... ok
checking for sysroot... no
checking for mt... no
checking if : is a manifest tool... no
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking for dlfcn.h... no
checking for objdir... .libs
checking if gcc supports -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions... no
checking for gcc option to produce PIC... -DDLL_EXPORT -DPIC
checking if gcc PIC flag -DDLL_EXPORT -DPIC works... yes
checking if gcc static flag -static works... yes
checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
checking whether the gcc linker (c:/mingw/x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe) supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether -lc should be explicitly linked in... yes
checking dynamic linker characteristics... Win32 ld.exe
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking whether stripping libraries is possible... yes
checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build static libraries... no
checking how to run the C++ preprocessor... g++ -E
checking for ld used by g++... c:/mingw/x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe
checking if the linker (c:/mingw/x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe) is GNU ld... yes
checking whether the g++ linker (c:/mingw/x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe) supports shared libraries... yes
checking for g++ option to produce PIC... -DDLL_EXPORT -DPIC
checking if g++ PIC flag -DDLL_EXPORT -DPIC works... yes
checking if g++ static flag -static works... yes
checking if g++ supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking if g++ supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
checking whether the g++ linker (c:/mingw/x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe) supports shared libraries... yes
checking dynamic linker characteristics... Win32 ld.exe
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking for dlfcn.h... (cached) no
checking for dlopen... no
checking for dlopen in -ldl... no
checking for sed... /usr/bin/sed
checking for perl... /usr/bin/perl
checking whether NLS is requested... yes
checking for msgfmt... no
checking for gmsgfmt... :
checking for xgettext... no
checking for msgmerge... no
checking for ld used by gcc... c:/mingw/x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe
checking if the linker (c:/mingw/x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe) is GNU ld... yes
checking for shared library run path origin... done
checking for CFPreferencesCopyAppValue... no
checking for CFLocaleCopyCurrent... no
checking for GNU gettext in libc... no
checking for iconv... no, consider installing GNU libiconv
checking for GNU gettext in libintl... no
checking whether to use NLS... no
checking for dlfcn.h... (cached) no
checking for dlopen in -ldl... (cached) no
checking if file locking and truncating is supported... no
checking if mmap and friends is supported... no
checking if file ino is supported... no
checking if posix locals are supported... no
checking if posix regex are supported... no
checking for nl_langinfo and CODESET... no
checking if posix mutexes are supported... no
configure: WARNING: Unable to find locking mechanism, Aspell will not be thread safe.
checking if mblen is supported... yes
checking for working curses library... not found
checking if posix termios is supported... no
checking for STL rel_ops pollution... no
checking that generated files are newer than configure... done
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating Makefile
config.status: creating gen/Makefile
config.status: creating common/Makefile
config.status: creating lib/Makefile
config.status: creating data/Makefile
config.status: creating auto/Makefile
config.status: creating modules/Makefile
config.status: creating modules/tokenizer/Makefile
config.status: creating modules/speller/Makefile
config.status: creating modules/speller/default/Makefile
config.status: creating interfaces/Makefile
config.status: creating interfaces/cc/Makefile
config.status: creating scripts/Makefile
config.status: creating examples/Makefile
config.status: creating prog/Makefile
config.status: creating manual/Makefile
config.status: creating po/Makefile.in
config.status: creating m4/Makefile
config.status: creating modules/filter/Makefile
config.status: creating myspell/Makefile
config.status: creating lib5/Makefile
config.status: creating gen/settings.h
config.status: gen/settings.h is unchanged
config.status: executing depfiles commands
config.status: executing libtool commands
config.status: executing po-directories commands
config.status: creating po/POTFILES
config.status: creating po/Makefile
```

And then when I type `make` I get the following error message:

```
    Making all in .
make[1]: Entering directory 'C:/aspell/aspell-0.60.7-rc1/aspell-0.60.7-rc1'
depbase=`echo common/cache.lo | sed 's|[^/]*$|.deps/&|;s|\.lo$||'`;\
C:/Program Files/Git/usr/bin/sh.exe ./libtool  --tag=CXX   --mode=compile g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I./gen  -I./gen -I./common -I./interfaces/cc/ -I./modules/speller/default/ -DLOCALEDIR="/usr/local/share/locale"   -g -O2 -fno-exceptions -MT common/cache.lo -MD -MP -MF $depbase.Tpo -c -o common/cache.lo common/cache.cpp &&\
mv -f $depbase.Tpo $depbase.Plo
/usr/bin/sh: line 1: C:/Program: No such file or directory
make[1]: *** [Makefile:1493: common/cache.lo] Error 127
make[1]: Leaving directory 'C:/aspell/aspell-0.60.7-rc1/aspell-0.60.7-rc1'
make: *** [Makefile:1626: all-recursive] Error 1
```

What is causing the issue?

Comment: We have no way of telling, because the error message you've included is just a summary that says that something went wrong. You'll need to include more context.

Comment: I added more error message after typing 'make'. If that is not sufficient, please let me know what other information is needed. I am new to this. Thanks

Comment: @Rob Would you be able to post the contents of the `Makefile` created in the directory that you are trying to invoke `make`, please?

Comment: @ViktorNonov `Makefile` contains 2136 lines. I've added a link to the source of this software in my question.

Comment: @Rob I see, one more clarifying question: Where do you run `./configure` and `make`? In the `Git Bash` or you start something different?

Comment: @ViktorNonov `Git Bash`

Comment: @Rob, Try to execute `export MAKESHELL=/bin/sh` and then run `make`

Comment: Unfortunately I still get the same error.